# Duplex printing for Brother MFC-J870DW

Tags: duplex-printing

I successfully (apparently) installed this printer using a driver specifically for this model downloaded from the Brother site, and am able to print, but although the printer is capable of printing duplex in Windows that option is "not available" in Ubuntu.  I am new to Ubuntu; I installed version 14.04 LTS. I have sent a message to Brother's Linux support group but to date have received no reply. Any information about how to resolve duplex printing issues would be helpful!

David